# How to make a distinct in only one table of a join using Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this query... and I would like to make a distinct only in (tbl_holdings)

This is my query

```
$holdings = DB::table('tbl_perimetros')
                ->distinct()
                ->join('tbl_holdings', 'tbl_holdings.id', '=', 'tbl_perimetros.holdings_id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: not really understand, can u post an example?

Comment: I don't want repeated values in tbl_holdings .. but I need the repeated values in tbl_perimetros

Comment: You can add a select clause and specify the column which you want to be unique or you may try ->distinct('tbl_holdings.columnname') should work.

Comment: you can use groupBy instead of distince.

Comment: how could I do that? @TsaiKoga

Comment: I tried to use ->distinct('tbl_holdings') but din't work @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: @Oscar compare what I have suggested and what you have tried is different :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupBy` instead of `distinct`:

```php
$holdings = DB::table('tbl_perimetros')
                ->groupBy('tbl_perimetros.holdings_id') 
                ->get();
```

#### Remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY:

Add `modes` to the config/database.php

```php
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'modes' => [
        'STRICT_ALL_TABLES',
        'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
        'NO_ZERO_DATE',
        'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
        'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
    ],
],
```

Comment: I did like this because I don't want select any column of tbl_holdings.......$holdings = DB::table('tbl_perimetros')
                ->groupBy('tbl_holdings.id')
                ->join('tbl_holdings', 'tbl_holdings.id', '=', 'tbl_perimetros.holdings_id')   
                ->get();

Comment: and I obtained this error ............. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bduempresas.tbl_perimetros.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `tbl_perimetros` inner join `tbl_holdings` on `tbl_holdings`.`id` = `tbl_perimetros`.`holdings_id` group by `tbl_holdings`.`id`)

Comment: if you don't want to select the `tbl_holdings`'s columns, you don't need to select it. and just group by the `tbl_perimetros.holdings_id`

Comment: but I need to make a join between tbl_perimetros and tbl_holdings and I dont want any repeated values In all columns of tbl_holdings

Comment: @Oscar I know, but you don't need those columns from `tbl_holdings`. And the duplicated value is the holdings_id in `tbl_permietros`. so you don't need to join it. just use the `groupBy('holdings_id')` can make the distinct. Unless you still need the columns from `tbl_holdings`

Comment: no... holdings_id is a foreing key  from tbl_perimetros that is making a match with the Id of tbl_holdings

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bduempresas.tbl_perimetros.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `tbl_perimetros` group by `tbl_perimetros`.`holdings_id`)

Comment: @Oscar this error occurs because the mysql version 5.7+ has only_full_group_by mode, you need to add `modes` to the config/database.php like my post.

Comment: is it possible to work with query builder in a model instead of work in the controller?

Comment: @Oscar yes,you can.

Comment: I would like to make a relation between three tables with Query Builder in a model instead of use eloquent method like hasMany or belongsTo... can you check my post?............ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101929/is-it-possible-to-work-in-a-model-with-query-builder-using-laravel/60102711?noredirect=1#comment106300421_60102711